# Pandas: How to format legend in MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm working at the moment on a plot with a MultiIndex Column. When I am trying to plot such data (as in the example below) in a diagram, I receive "(Semester1,Maths)","(Semester1,Science)" and so on in the legend.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Semester1','Semester2'],['Maths','Science']])
d=([[12,45,67,56],[78,89,45,67],[45,67,89,90],[67,44,56,55]])


df = pd.DataFrame(d,
                  index=['Alisa','Bobby','Cathrine','Jack'],
                  columns=header)
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

I know that it is possible to set the legends text by hand, but is there also a way to use the Columns as a kind of variable, so that I can for example automatically adjust the legend to the format "Semester1, Maths" instead of "(Semester 1,Maths)"?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: `df.columns=df.columns.map(','.join)
`

Answer (score 2):

You could replace the column index with the desired values before calling `plot`:

```
In [650]: df.set_axis(header.map(', '.join), axis=1, inplace=False)
Out[650]: 
          Semester1, Maths  Semester1, Science  Semester2, Maths  Semester2, Science
Alisa                   12                  45                67                  56
Bobby                   78                  89                45                  67
Cathrine                45                  67                89                  90
Jack                    67                  44                56                  55
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Semester1','Semester2'],['Maths','Science']])
d=([[12,45,67,56],[78,89,45,67],[45,67,89,90],[67,44,56,55]])

df = pd.DataFrame(d,
                  index=['Alisa','Bobby','Cathrine','Jack'],
                  columns=header)
df.set_axis(header.map(', '.join), axis=1, inplace=False).plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

[image]